# CSS background image

Tags: html, css, background

My background image is not working using css here is the code:

```css
.content {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 60vw;
    background-image: "https://www.askideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Free-Online-Photos1.jpg";
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content col-lg-12">


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run the code the background image is not showing up.
How can I fix my `CSS` and/or `HMTL` so that my background image is working?

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `url()`:

```css
.content {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 60vw;
    background-image: url("https://www.askideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Free-Online-Photos1.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content col-lg-12">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the image url in `url`. It's also worth noting that there are additional properties you may want to include, such as `background-size`, `background-repeat`, `background-position`, etc.

```css
    .content {
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: grey;
        height: 60vw;
        background-image: url("https://www.askideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Free-Online-Photos1.jpg");
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content col-lg-12">


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax should be:

```
background-image: url(https://www.askideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Free-Online-Photos1.jpg);
```

The *url* keyword and *wrapping parenthesis* are required.

[background-image - CSS - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.content {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 60vw;
    background-image: url(https://www.askideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Free-Online-Photos1.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content col-lg-12">


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```